# Internal storage mechanism for Events

Tags: c#, events

```
class Control: Component
{
   // Unique keys for events
   static readonly object mouseDownEventKey = new object();
   static readonly object mouseUpEventKey = new object();
   // Return event handler associated with key
   protected Delegate GetEventHandler(object key) {...}
   // Add event handler associated with key
   protected void AddEventHandler(object key, Delegate handler) {...}
   // Remove event handler associated with key
   protected void RemoveEventHandler(object key, Delegate handler) {...}
   // MouseDown event
   public event MouseEventHandler MouseDown {
      add { AddEventHandler(mouseDownEventKey, value); }
      remove { RemoveEventHandler(mouseDownEventKey, value); }
   }
   // MouseUp event
   public event MouseEventHandler MouseUp {
      add { AddEventHandler(mouseUpEventKey, value); }
      remove { RemoveEventHandler(mouseUpEventKey, value); }
   }
   // Invoke the MouseUp event
   protected void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs args) {
      MouseEventHandler handler;
      handler = (MouseEventHandler)GetEventHandler(mouseUpEventKey);
      if (handler != null)
         handler(this, args);
   }
}
```

> the Control class implements an internal storage mechanism for events.
>   The AddEventHandler method associates a delegate value with a key, the
>   GetEventHandler method returns the delegate currently associated with
>   a key, and the RemoveEventHandler method removes a delegate as an
>   event handler for the specified event. Presumably, the underlying
>   storage mechanism is designed such that there is no cost for
>   associating a null delegate value with a key, and thus unhandled
>   events consume no storage.

This code and the explanation in the paragraph above don't make any sense to me. Any idea what this internal storage mechanism is all about? And what does associating a delegate with an abject mean in the paragraph above?

Comment: I can recommend the Jeffrey Rechter's book "CLR via C#" if you want to understand it in depth. There is special chapter (about ~30-40pages) describing events and delegates in all details and with enough explanation how they are stored.

Answer (score 3):

The Windows Forms controls expose a large number of events. A typical UI would be composed of a large number of these controls.

When you use the standard event syntax

```
public event MouseEventHandler MouseDown;
```

The compiler generates the `add` and `remove` methods and a private field of the same type as the delegate.

This means that a lot of memory will be taken up by default (even with no events subscribed).

The Windows Forms controls defines their own storage method which means that memory is only used for events that are actually subscribed (plus the object that stores the delegates E.G. a Dictionary), reducing the overall memory footprint of the application.

The delegates are associated with an object key so that if, for example, the `Mousedown` event occurs it can look up the delegates that apply to that event so that they can be invoked.

Comment: .Net Reflector sheds a little more light on this - the event handlers are stored in a linked list - `System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the situation, this storage mechanism was created generally for maintain weak reference pattern. Check this article to go deeper in it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx